# When I upload image assets to my Experience Cloud site, Salesforce compresses them and they have poor quality

Tags: files, experience-cloud, images, asset, cdn

I am using an out-of-the-box theme & standard components like the hero component. The images I upload to the site get compressed to a very small file size (less than 2 KB) when served up to the client. The file gets appended with a query string: `v=1`. If this is removed, I can access the file in its full quality.

What causes this compression?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the issue is caused by [the "Display Images Faster on All Devices" setting in Experience Cloud](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_files_optimize_images_all_devices.htm&type=5).

1. Go to Experience Workspaces
2. Open **Administration** > **Preferences**
3. Uncheck **Optimize cached images for guest users on all devices**